# Heatmap with matplotlib using matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap of a 10x10 matrix. All values in the matrix are probabilities; sum of all elements equal to 1.0. I decided to use the matshow plot type (it seemed easy to use), however I cannot generate the output I'd like to have so far.

1.Visually it looks kinda ugly. Would you recommend a fitting color map for use in a heatmap?

2.Is there a way to assign predefined bins to the color map when using matshow? E.g. take a gradient of 1000 colors, always use the same colors for the corresponding probabilities. In default behavior, I think matshow checks the minimum and maximum values, assigned the first and last colors in the gradient to those values, then colorizes the values in between by interpolation.

Sometimes I have very similar probabilities in the matrix, and other times the range of probabilities may be great. Due to the default behavior I tried to explain above, I get similar plots, which makes comparisons harder.

My code for generating the said heat maps (and an example plot) is below by the way.

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pickcoord():
    i = np.random.randint(0,10)
    j = np.random.randint(0,10)
    return [i,j]

board = np.zeros((10,10))
for i in range(1000000):

    try:
        direction = np.random.randint(0,2)
        new_board = np.zeros((10,10))
        coords = pickcoord()

        if direction == 1:
            for k in range(2):
                new_board[coords[0]][coords[1]+k] = 1
        else:
            for k in range(2):
                new_board[coords[0]+k][coords[1]] = 1

    except IndexError:
        new_board = np.zeros((10,10))

    board = board + new_board

board_prob = board/np.sum(board)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.matshow(board_prob, cmap=matplotlib.cm.Spectral_r, interpolation='none')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5,10.5), [])
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5,10.5), [])
plt.grid()
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your second problem can be solved using the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments of the `matshow` function:

```
matshow(board_prob, cmap=cm.Spectral_r, interpolation='none', vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

Considering your first problem, it depends on what you want to emphasize or display. Choose a fitting colormap from the [default colormaps of matplotlib](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps).